# Downgrade Windows 10 to Windows 10 S

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10s

I have an old Windows 10 Home laptop that I never use. The main reason why I don't use it is because it is so slow. If I install Windows 10 S on it, it'll probably become more relaxing to use.

What is the best way to do this? Is there a way to use the same license (convert, or use the same) or do I need to buy a license?

Comment: Your best alternative is chromeOS

Comment: Windows 10 S is only given to OEMs for new devices.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Technically true, but developers can also download it, with an applicable VS subscription. Important distinction compare to say Windows RT which was only sold through hardware channels.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks @sziraqui! I don’t know why I did not think of that. I’ll do that.

Comment: yes, but MSDN licenses are only valid for development systems/purpose, so no advice here from us to use such a license for normal usage.

Comment: I will develop on it though, so that wouldn’t be a problem. But I still think I’ll install Chrome OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best way to do this?

This cannot be done.

> If you make the switch, you won't be able to go back to Windows 10 S.

[Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4020089/windows-10-s-faq)

> Is there a way to use the same license

A Windows 10 Home license cannot be used to activate a Windows 10 S installation.  There is no path from Windows 10 S to Windows 10 Home or vice versa.

> do I need to buy a license?

You cannot buy a Windows 10 S license by itself.  You must buy hardware that comes with it.  Windows 10 S licenses cannot be transferred.  Worth pointing out that any sources for Windows 10 S other than hardware that comes with it or a qualified MSDN subscription is a scam.

You would have to reinstall Windows 10 in order to downgrade to Windows 10 S if you do happen to have a qualified MSDN subscription.

> The main reason why I don't use it is because it is so slow. If I install Windows 10 S on it, it'll probably become more relaxing to use.

Even if it was possible to downgrade to Windows 10 S from a Windows 10 Home installation it wouldn’t solve your performance problems.  Whatever is slowing your installation down would be migrated to the new installation due to how the process would work (it would be identically to how Windows 10 Reset works and/or how feature updates are installed.
Windows has never supported downgrading to a lower version.